# Django class-based ListView vs function-based list_view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

So I'm trying to wrap my head around the following issue. The Class-based view for customer_list works like a charm, it show a list of all customers residing in the customer tabel. However, the function based view, which should do exactly the same returns empty.

Maybe there's something I'm missing but I just want to know how both views differ and when to use what.

If there's someone who could explain what I'm missing?

## urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

# Function based view
url(r'^all_customers/$', views.customer_list, name='all_customers'),
   
# Class based view
url(r'^all_customers/$', views.customer_list.as_view(),name='all_customers'),
```

## views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Customer

# Function based view
def customer_list(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'all_customers.html', {'customers': customers})

# Class based view
class CustomerList(generic.ListView):
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'all_customers.html'
```

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And this is a section of the template

```
{% for customer in customer_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{customer.pk}}</td>
    <td>
    {% if customer.prefix %}
        {{customer.first_name}}  {{customer.prefix}}  {{customer.last_name}}
    {% else %}
        {{customer.first_name}}  {{customer.last_name}}
    {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: change in function based customer_list() --  {'customers': customers}  to  {'customer_list' : customers} in your html you are using customer_list not customers

Comment: Cheers, I've been staring at this for a while now!

Answer (score 0):

your import is wrong in urls.py 
you should use from .views import customer_list

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details.